# How to toggle class on mousedown/mouseup in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to toggle a class in a react component where if a user has his mouse down on a button, then it'll add a class to that button and when the user has his mouseup, then it reverts back and removes the class from the button.

Following the explanations and examples in the official ReactJS docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), I managed to put together the following snippet but it's not working and keeps throwing syntax errors on the console:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Buttons extends React.Component{

    toggleClass() {
        if this.classList.has('btnDown') {
            this.classList.remove('btnDown');
        } else {
            this.classList.add('btnDown');
        }
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div className="btn-wrap">
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '1' >1</button>
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '2' >2</button>
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '3' >3</button>
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '4' >4</button>
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '5' >5</button>
                <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '6' >6</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

I rewrote the component to use react's `state` using @TomaszMularczyk's answer below as a reference but now all the buttons are toggled instead of just the button clicked as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/183164/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` will not be an HTML element, but React Object instance.

I would try more reactive way to achieve this and used `state`:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDown: false
    };
  }

  toggleClass() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isDown: !prevState.isDown }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className={this.state.isDown ? "btnDown" : ""}
        onMouseDown={e => this.toggleClass(e)}
        onMouseUp={e => this.toggleClass(e)}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}

export class Buttons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="btn-wrap">
        <Button value="1">1</Button>
        <Button value="2">2</Button>
        ....
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the toggleClass method with yours and got a `Syntax error: Unexpected token` pointing to the word `event` instead. I tried repalcing `event` with the letter `e` and got the same error but pointing at e.

Comment: This removes the error but it seems to be adding the `btnDown` class to the div wrap and not the buttons inside.

Comment: I tried fiddling with what you gave me above and managed to target the buttons instead but now, the class is added to all of them instead of just the clicked one.

Comment: Let me try to replicate this on jsfiddle. Hold on.

Comment: @AndrewL oh you need to toggle that class on each button... See the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for following up on this but the above isn't rendering anything at all as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/183166/

Comment: @AndrewL it works. It's just that JsFiddle can't handle `export` keyword. Try to remove it.

Comment: @AndrewL it's a callback function. It all has to do with that `setState` is asynchronous. So to make sure updates are up-to-date it's best to use a [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own Button component

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDown: false
    };
  }

  toggleClass() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isDown: !prevState.isDown }));
  }  

  render() {
    const className = `${this.state.isDown ? "btnDown" : ""}`;
    return <button className={className} onMouseDown={e => this.toggleClass(e)} value={this.props.value} {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</button>
  }
}
```

And then use those instead of the html button -

```
<div className="btn-wrap">
    <Button value = '1'>1</Button>
    <Button value = '2'>2</Button>
    <Button value = '3'>3</Button>
    <Button value = '+' onClick={e => console.log('+ clicked')}>3</Button>
    <Button value = '-' onClick={e => console.log('- clicked')}>3</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement the above in jsfiddle but it's not loading for some weird reason: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/183165/

Comment: your first jsfiddle has syntax errors. Can you please correct those and share again?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `this` inside `toggleClass`, use the event object :

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
    toggleClass(e) {
      if(e.target.classList.contains('btnDown')) {
        e.target.classList.remove('btnDown');
      } else {
        e.target.classList.add('btnDown');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="btn-wrap">
          <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '1' >1</button>
          <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '2' >2</button>
          <button onMouseDown={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} onMouseUp={(e) => this.toggleClass(e)} value = '3' >3</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

The css was taken from @Tomasz Mularczyk's answer.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gddLwgme/)

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you! +1 But as @Tomasz showed in his answer, what would be the right way to do this using react `state`?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a little bit, it should work properly now:

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
         isDown: null
      };

  }

  pressButton = (i) => {
    this.setState({ isDown: i });
  };
  releaseButton = () => {
    this.setState({ isDown: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { isDown } = this.state;
    const buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, '+', '-'];

    return (
      <div className="btn-wrap">
        {buttons.map((button, i) => (
          <button
            className={`${isDown === i ? 'btnDown' : ''}`}
            onMouseDown={this.pressButton.bind(undefined, i)}
            onMouseUp={this.releaseButton}
            value={button}
          >
            {button}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);`
```